How do I take individual letters and spaces from a variable and then use those letters to call a function
Here is my code(I know it's probably inefficient):
import time
from time import sleep
import winsound as win

frequency = 1000
duration = 250

frequency1 = 1000
duration1 = 500

def short():
    sleep(0.1)

def med():
    sleep(0.75)

def long():
    sleep(1.5)

def lb():
    win.Beep(frequency1,duration1)

def sb():
    win.Beep(frequency,duration)

def a():
    sb()
    short()
    lb()

def b():
    lb()
    short()
    sb()
    short()
    sb()
    short()
    sb()

def c():
    lb()
    short()
    sb()
    short()
    lb()
    short()
    sb()

def d():
    lb()
    short()
    sb()

def e():
    sb()

def f():
    sb()
    short()
    sb()
    short()
    lb()
    short()
    sb()

def g():
    lb()
    short()
    lb()
    short()
    sb()

def h():
    sb()
    short()
    sb()
    short()
    sb()
    short()
    sb()

def i():
    sb()
    short()
    sb()

def j():
    sb()
    short()
    lb()
    short()
    lb()
    short()
    lb()

def k():
    lb()
    short()
    sb()
    short()
    lb()

def l():
    sb()
    short()
    lb()
    short()
    sb()
    short()
    sb()

def m():
    lb()
    short()
    lb()

def n():
    lb()
    short()
    sb()

def o():
    lb()
    short()
    lb()
    short()
    lb()

def p():
    sb()
    short()
    lb()
    short()
    lb()
    short()
    sb()

def q():
    lb()
    short()
    lb()
    short()
    sb()
    short()
    lb()

def r():
    sb()
    short()
    lb()
    short()
    sb()
    
def s():
    sb()
    short()
    sb()
    short()
    sb()

def t():
    lb()

def u():
    sb()
    short()
    sb()
    short()
    lb()

def v():
    sb()
    short()
    sb()
    short()
    sb()
    short()
    lb()

def w():
    sb()
    short()
    lb()
    short()
    lb()

def x():
    lb()
    short()
    sb()
    short()
    sb()
    short()
    lb()

def y():
    lb()
    short()
    sb()
    short()
    lb()
    short()
    lb()

def z():
    lb()
    short()
    lb()
    short()
    sb()
    short()
    sb()


translate = input("What should be translated into morse code?")

for letter in translate:
    letter()

How do I take out a single letter at a time from translate and go through all the letters in translate and use those to call functions, like if translate = "hi" then it goes through translate and takes out the h and then calls a function in this case h() and then call it something like this, letter() and then continues going through translate.
I just tried letter() and I was expecting it to most likely not work.

You make a dictionary of string to functions and then call the correct letter. - {"a": a}. my_dict[letter]()

I changed a bit of code at the end to this:     translate = input("What should be translated into morse code?")
letters = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(translate))
for letter in letters:
letter()

Thanks Sayse I've got it working now

Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.

Firstly you need to define your letter() function, thats why it was not working. Secondly the best way to iterate through your string and call the appropriate function for each letter is as Sayse suggest in the first comment. Add your letters to a dictionary and then call the appropriate function.
import time

from time import sleep
import winsound as win

frequency = 1000
duration = 250

frequency1 = 1000
duration1 = 500

def short():
    sleep(0.1)

def med():
    sleep(0.75)

def long():
    sleep(1.5)


def lb():
    win.Beep(frequency1,duration1)

def sb():
    win.Beep(frequency,duration)

def a():
    sb()
    short()
    lb()

def b():
    lb()
    short()
    sb()
    short()
    sb()
    short()
    sb()

def c():
    lb()
    short()
    sb()
    short()
    lb()
    short()
    sb()

def d():
    lb()
    short()
    sb()

def e():
    sb()

def f():
    sb()
    short()
    sb()
    short()
    lb()
    short()
    sb()

def g():
    lb()
    short()
    lb()
    short()
    sb()

def h():
    sb()
    short()
    sb()
    short()
    sb()
    short()
    sb()

def i():
    sb()
    short()
    sb()

def j():
    sb()
    short()
    lb()
    short()
    lb()
    short()
    lb()

def k():
    lb()
    short()
    sb()
    short()
    lb()

def l():
    sb()
    short()
    lb()
    short()
    sb()
    short()
    sb()

def m():
    lb()
    short()
    lb()

def n():
    lb()
    short()
    sb()

def o():
    lb()
    short()
    lb()
    short()
    lb()

def p():
    sb()
    short()
    lb()
    short()
    lb()
    short()
    sb()

def q():
    lb()
    short()
    lb()
    short()
    sb()
    short()
    lb()

def r():
    sb()
    short()
    lb()
    short()
    sb()
    
def s():
    sb()
    short()
    sb()
    short()
    sb()

def t():
    lb()

def u():
    sb()
    short()
    sb()
    short()
    lb()

def v():
    sb()
    short()
    sb()
    short()
    sb()
    short()
    lb()

def w():
    sb()
    short()
    lb()
    short()
    lb()

def x():
    lb()
    short()
    sb()
    short()
    sb()
    short()
    lb()

def y():
    lb()
    short()
    sb()
    short()
    lb()
    short()
    lb()

def z():
    lb()
    short()
    lb()
    short()
    sb()
    short()
    sb()

morse_code_dict = {
    'a': a,
    'b': b,
    'c': c,
    'd': d,
    'e': e,
    'f': f,
    'g': g,
    'h': h,
    'i': i,
    'j': j,
    'k': k,
    'l': l,
    'm': m,
    'n': n,
    'o': o,
    'p': p,
    'q': q,
    'r': r,
    's': s,
    't': t,
    'u': u,
    'v': v,
    'w': w,
    'x': x,
    'y': y,
    'z': z
}

# Function to call the appropriate letter function
def letters(input_string):
    for letter in input_string.lower():
        if letter in morse_code_dict:
            morse_code_dict[letter]()
        else:
            print(f"Character '{letter}' not supported in Morse code.")

translate = 'hi'
letters(translate)

 

